# laser_scan_matcher error!

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello friends...
I am using gmapping and it is working fine with fake odometry. But now I wanted to use laser_scan_matcher to get better odometry data. I am not use a bag file and rosparam use_sim_time is "false". But laser_scan_matcher throws some error.
I couldnt solve this. (I am using static tf for laser to base_link)

error link :
[http://i.imgur.com/oA6q09I.png](https://i.imgur.com/oA6q09I.png)

And this is my laser_scan_matcher.launch file:

```
 <launch>
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>  
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node"   
name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">    
<param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>    
<param name="use_imu" type="bool" value="false" />    
<param name="use_odom" type="bool" value="false" />    
<param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="world" />    
<param name="base_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
</node>
</launch>**
```

my error:

```
****process[laser_scan_matcher_node-1]: started with pid [36778]
[ INFO] [1435132670.287163697]: Starting LaserScanMatcher

[ WARN] [1435132671.572234872]: Could not get initial transform from base to laser frame, Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1435132670.566868328 but the earliest data is at time 1435132670.570998429, when looking up transform from frame [laser] to frame [base_link]

[ WARN] [1435132671.572301017]: Skipping scan
Strange FOV: -6.283185 rad = -360.000010 deg 
[ WARN] [1435132671.572614765]: Error in scan matching****
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211985/laser_scan_matcher-error!/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this error was solved like that: Error is relates to Rplidar node.cpp.
http://geduino.blogspot.com.tr/2015/04/gmapping-and-rplidar.html

```
Modify the original code:
 
scan_msg.angle_min = M_PI - angle_min;
scan_msg.angle_max = M_PI - angle_max;
 
to:
 
scan_msg.angle_min = -1*(M_PI - angle_min);
scan_msg.angle_max = M_PI - angle_min;
```

https://gist.github.com/Po-Jen

---

Originally posted by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) with karma: 153 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23646/rosrabbit/) on 2015-08-26**:
Thanks! That works for me!

**Comment by [jrobe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26819/jrobe/) on 2016-05-10**:
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-07-09**:
Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [danthb](https://answers.ros.org/users/36386/danthb/) on 2018-11-22**:
Could you help me with the modification I should do, if I'm using a ydlidar?